# How to parse HTML in Windows Store apps?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I've downloaded the source code of a web page, and I want to parse and converter the HTML text to something like **HtmlDocument** object or Interface so I can access the HTML element in it.

I've done some search online. It seems besides using **HtmlAgilityPack** library, the only possible way to go is to create a **WebView** and call its **NavigateToString**() method. I don't want to use third-party library, so I tried the 2nd solution. I have called the method, but I don't know where to retrieve the **Document** or something like it.

So my question is: How to retrieve HtmlDocument from a WebView? Or is there any better solution to do this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a third party library? They are often the easiest way to get a piece of functionality up and running, especially for features that aren't well provided for by default.

Comment: The reason is pretty simple: sometimes, the introduce of third party library means extra concerns: robust, performance, version control, portability,etc. I've been trying to keep my code base as simple as possible. So in principle I have to prefer native solution than 3rd party if there is any. No offence! Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: No offence taken don't worry. I only asked because some people seem to have an illogical fear of third party components, which can often lead to wasted time and effort. Pragmatic software development is all about building on the work of others to reach even loftier heights.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the HTML? If you let us know that, maybe we can provide alternate solutions that don't involve having to parse the HTML at all?

Comment: Hi, Todd, I totally understand what you mean and thanks for your help.I am migrating a Win32 application to WinRT. Some of the modules of it involve converting the html text to IHtmlDocument interface using COM and then using DOM to distill data from it. But I can't find alternative solution in WinRT. That's the whole story.

Comment: If you eventually *do accept* 3rd party solutions to your problem, you might also want to take a look at [AngleSharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp). This is a portable class library for different types of HTML parsing that targets Windows Store.

Comment: Hi, Anders, I've just given a quick look at the online examples of AngleSharp, it seems that this 3rd party library is just what I am looking for. Comparing to HtmlAgilityPack, it is based on DOM which I am more familiar than XPATH, so it would be much to migrating the old win32 code. Thanks! If you would like to re-post this comment as an answer, I'll mark it accepted. And thanks to Todd too, you men are really two good person. Love you!

Comment: So your fear of third party libraries has to do with robustness and performance, and yet you choose a library that's in early alpha instead of one that has been around for years because you like it's coding style better. Does that really make sense to you?

Comment: Hi, Karl, I forgot to mention that I am not a professional programmer. I just want to migrate a Delphi win32 application and do it as simple as possible. I am not familiar with XPATH, so for the sake of safety, I prefer AngleSharp. XPath and DOM are two of the most popular models to parse HTML, so the coexist of these two libraries are very important for WinRT developers. They basically provide two different choices to parse html.If time permits, I would  like to test both solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Todd Bowles also points out in the comments above, if a third-party solution exists, using it can often save you valuable time and effort.

An alternative to [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), although still at a fairly early stage, is [AngleSharp](https://github.com/FlorianRappl/AngleSharp). It can parse various bracket based hypertexts, in particular HTML and CSS, and it produces a HTML5 DOM representation of the parsed hypertext. At the moment the HTML5 parser is claimed to be 95% complete, hopefully this will have limited impact on regular usage though.

*AngleSharp* is implemented as a *Portable Class Library* (PCL) and if I am correct it targets *Windows Store apps*, *.NET Framework 4* and higher, *Windows Phone 7* and higher, as well as *Silverlight 4* and higher.

Comment: The 95% is a defensive estimate. Most tests (currently around 1600) deal with HTML(5) (edge) cases. If AngleSharp does not parse it correctly, then HAP or other solutions won't parse it the right way either.